# Ansible: Chocolatey - remove_dependencies abandoned?

Tags: ansible, yaml, ansible-2.x, chocolatey

I am using ansible to remove python on a windows VM (hence chocolatey) that I have.

I get this error when I set remove_dependencies to yes.

```
"changed": false, "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (win_chocolatey module: remove_dependencies. Supported parameters include: proxy_username, timeout, source, name, soure_password, ignore_dependencies, source_username, architecture, ignore_checksums, allow_multiple, validte_certs, proxy_password, allow_prerelease, skip_scripts, allow_empty_checksums, proxy_url, state, packge_params, pinned, force, install_args, execution_timeout, params"}
```

On ansible's website under their chocolatey documentation, remove_dependencies is still listed. I did not find anything about it being deprecated. (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/chocolatey/chocolatey/win_chocolatey_module.html). Is there an update I may have missed? Can anyone fill me in on what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem. Not sure if it is the right one but it works. If you set `force: yes` then it forces the uninstall